# How to use Redis cache in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, predis

It's my first time to use Laravel and Redis. I understand how to get, set, etc of Redis on Terminal. But **no idea how to apply Redis on Laravel application.**
I have application that saves participant's information in DB with MVC pattern. and I'd like to change it to use Redis cache to make it faster(and for practice). What do I have to do? **Could you explain it with code?**

This is ParticipantController. 'edit' function send user to edit page, and user edit the information and push 'save', it activate 'update' function. store/updateUserInput functions are just saving data to DB nothing else.

```
   /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified participant.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return View
     */
    public function edit(int $id): View
    {
        $participant = Participant::find($id);
        if(empty($participant)){
            return view('errors.404');
        }
        return view('participants.edit', ['participant'=>$participant]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified participant in storage.
     *
     * @param ParticipantValidation $request
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function update(ParticipantValidation $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $participant = Participant::find($request->id);
        if(empty($participant)){
            return view('errors.404');
        }
        $detail = $request->all();
        Participant::updateUserInput($detail);
        return redirect()->route('participants.create', $detail['event_id'])->with('success', 'Updated!');
    }
```

+plus I tried this code on top of 'Controller' to use sth like `$redis->set('message', 'Hello world');` but there's error that they cannot find 'Predis/Autoload.php'

```
require 'Predis/Autoload.php';
PredisAutoloader::register();

try {
    $redis = new PredisClient();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cache facade

In your .env file, you must add `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`

Then whenever you want to get an instance of Participant:

```
$participant = null;
$key ="Participant".$id;
if(Cache::has($key)//get participant from cache
    $participant = Cache::get($key);
else{//get participant and cache for 3 minutes
    $participant = Participant::find($id);
    $seconds = 180;
    Cache::set($key, $participant, $seconds);
}
```

Comment: This can be greatly simplified to `$participant = Cache::remember('participant_' . $id, 180, function () use($id) { return Participant::find($id); });`

Comment: Sick! I wouldn't have thought to add a closure as the default

Comment: `$participant = Cache::remember("participant_$id", 180, fn() => Participant::find($id));`